# how to search letter in span value with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want search one letter for example **a** in many spans and I want if exist in span show this span and hide others.

```
<span id="1">janatan</span>
<span id="2">john</span>
<span id="3">jarry</span>
<span id="4">marry</span>
<span id="5">dfdgdf</span>
<span id="6">ghjkgk</span>
```

Comment: Post what you've tried

Comment: btw, id shouldn't begin with a digit, it's invalid HTML.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('span').each(function(){
    if (this.innerHTML.indexOf('a') > -1)
    // or using  toLowerCase() if needed
    if (this.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf('a') > -1)
        $(this).show();
    else
        $(this).hide();
});
```

Or with:

```
$('span').hide().filter(':contains(a)').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

I will give you the bricks :

- `$('span')` will retrieve every `span` (like a css selector)
- `.each(function(){ ... $(this).text() ... })` will iterate on each element and apply the function on `this`.
- above, `.text()` will get you the text inside an element
- `.show()` and `.hide()` to show or hide an element
- `.siblings('span')` to select every child of the same parent but this one.

Have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use :contains to get elements based on their content.

```
<div>This is a test</div>

<div>Div</div>
<div>a</div>

$('div:contains("a")').css('display', 'block');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9z5du/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('span').each(function(){
    if(/a/ig.test($(this).text())){
        $(this).show();
    }else{
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

---

**or**

```
$('span').hide().filter(function(){
    return /a/ig.test($(this).text());     
}).show();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (this.innerHTML.indexOf('A') > -1)
```

[DEMO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bnsUR/4/)

Comment: @gdoron no it has cap `A` lol

Comment: @TecHunter, that's the funny part, I wrote `'A'` in the beginning and edited it as I noticed he wrote `'a'`... :) but the demo is using the code after the edit. `LOL`

Comment: @gdoron I would add a toLowerCase() though :)